# htaccess get part of the url to create new url

Tags: .htaccess

My old url is like this

```
http://example.com/dir/999-name/profile.html
```

Now I would like to redirect all those urls to the ones shown below

```
http://example.com/dir/profile/999-name.html
```

I tried with the below one but is not working

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)/(.*)$ /dir/profile/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Can someone help me getting the htaccess redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]*)/(.*).html$ /dir/$2/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```